# Buttons not working on iOS 8.4.1

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, onsen-ui

After I upgrade to iOS 8.4.1 release, my application buttons stopped working. The item list works, but the buttons do not work anymore .

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Same issue. If I don't use ons-button, but use a normal <button>, it works. If I added the onsen css classes to that same plain <button>, it breaks.

Comment: I setted the css property to `button:active { opacity: 1; !important }` and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

As you already reported on Onsen UI GitHub issue page, just updating Fastclick library fixes the issue (Onsen 1.2.2), but this is not the right approach. Onsen 1.3.8 works fine, so I suggest you to update to the latest version.